# How to make scaffold for two entities relations with Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I designed DB like "Team <- Member".
I would like to make Member entity associated with Team Name in Team entity.
But I have no idea to retrieve Team names that member is joining.

```
  members = Repo.all(Member)
  teams = Repo.all(Team)
  assign(conn, :teams, teams)
  render(conn, "index.html", members: members)
```

It retrieves condition "select * from members M left join teams T on T.id = M.team_id" like this.

*** Question ***

1. How to get Team names in index.html.eex like this layout?

In case of rails,

[image: index]

2. How to write Team name for show.html.eex like this layout?
   [image: show]

<%= member.team.team_name> or <%= teams.team_name %> 
But does not work I expect.

3. How to write Team in the select tag in form.html.eex like this layout?
   [image: form]

<%= select f, :team_id, @teams %> also does not work I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repo.preload(:team) can work like RoR.

member_controller.ex

```
plug :load_teams when action in [:new, :edit]

defp load_teams(conn, _ ) do
  query = from(t in Team, select: {t.team_name, t.id}) 
  teams = Repo.all(query)
  conn
  |> assign(:teams, teams)
end

def index(conn, _params) do
  members = Member |> Repo.all() |> Repo.preload(:team)
  render(conn, "index.html", members: members)
end

def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  member = Member |> Repo.get!(id) |> Repo.preload(:team)
  render(conn, "show.html", member: member)
end
```

index.html.eex

```
 <%= for member <- @members do %>
   <%= member.team.team_name %>
 <% end %>
```

show.html.eex

```
<%= member.team.team_name %>
```

form.html.eex

```
<%= render "form.html", changeset: @changeset,
                    teams: @teams,
                    action: member_path(@conn, :create) %>
```

new/edit.html.eex

```
<%= select f, :team_id, @teams, class: "form-control" %>
```

member.ex

```
schema "members" do
  belongs_to :team, PhoenixSample.Team
  timestamps()
end
```

I made it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified in migrations that the very schema contains references to other table eg. in your case schema `Member` would contain reference to `Team`. It means that member table contain `team_id` in it.

To use it, you have to modify your schema in `Team` schema (old model) by adding proper `belongs_to` to Member and `has_one` vice versa.

Then, you should be able to retrieve team for the particular member. Then, querying for the team's name should be very easy.

eg.

```
import Ecto.Query
import Ecto
team_name_query = from m in Member, where: m.id == ^selected_id, join: t in assoc(m, :team), select: {m.id, t.name}
```